# How to generate the most valuable words for each topic in LDA from vowpall_wabbit?

Tags: lda, vowpalwabbit

I have a model of LDA built from a vowpal wabbit. In [tutorial](http://mlwave.com/tutorial-online-lda-with-vowpal-wabbit/) I've seen that it is possible to print most valuables words foreach topic like this

```
Topic 1
0.997 printf
0.997 sizeof
0.996 characters
0.996 character
0.995 endl
0.995 stdio
0.994 iostream
0.993 cout
0.992 unsigned
0.991 malloc
0.991 typedef
0.991 cin
0.991 argc
0.989 size_t
0.988 len
0.988 std
0.986 unicode
0.986 ascii
0.986 fprintf
0.986 scanf

Topic 2
0.999 img
0.999 div
0.999 width
0.999 height
0.999 png
0.999 jquery
0.999 alt
0.999 imgur
0.999 css
0.999 border
0.999 margin
0.998 1px
0.998 color
0.998 jsfiddle
0.998 0px
0.998 getelementbyid
0.998 addsubview
0.998 jpg
0.998 alloc
0.998 cgrectmake

Topic 3
1.0 about
1.0 question
1.0 we
1.0 looking
1.0 best
0.999 good
0.999 since
0.999 better
0.999 say
0.999 their
0.999 wondering
0.999 most
0.999 computer
0.999 such
0.999 our
0.999 were
0.999 own
0.999 really
0.999 might
0.999 think

Topic 4
0.997 eventargs
0.996 mysql_query
0.996 linq
0.996 varchar
0.995 actionresult
0.995 ienumerable
0.995 lastname
0.995 firstname
0.994 tolist
0.994 entity
0.994 writeline
0.993 sqlcommand
0.993 dbo
0.993 user_id
0.993 binding
0.992 userid
0.992 datatable
0.992 databind
0.991 byval
0.991 connectionstring
```

Does anyone know how to produce such output when I only have file with a model?

Comment: You mean you want to.. let's say "decompile" the model file.. right?

Comment: Well, I haven't played with lda, but 99% sure its model file is made alike other learning regimes. This means it doesn't stores feature names - only their hashes, so you can't get readable model from it. But i wrote a small enhancement for VW that I hope to contribute to master branch in coming months that reads the model file and dataset it trained from and prints out feature names if hashes matches.

Comment: So if you have an original dataset we can try to reverse the model trained from it (haven't try it with lda models yet). Or, perhaps, i can even try just an English text corpus to demangle the hashes. Anyway, if you're able to build VW from sources and has some c++ skills I can instruct you or i'll need your model and dataset (which you're most probably doesn't have?).